# Why am I unable to fetch PGP keys from commandline?

Tags: pgp, gnupg

I hit this issue several times with different calls of `gpg` (recommended in tutorials).
This time it is:

```
$ gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 0x4ABA2F66DBD5A95894910E0673D770CDA59047B9
gpg: requesting key A59047B9 from hkp server pgp.mit.edu
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

However I am able to download it from http://pgp.mit.edu and then import.

I wonder why is the PGP client failing - or maybe why the keyserver has disabled possibility of fetching key by the client?

Comment: You are probably using a proxy in the browser but have no browser configured for the gpg command line or vice versa. Anyway, this is off-topic in my opinion.

Comment: I do not use proxy in my browser. What do you mean by "have browser configured for the gpg command line"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HKP, the "HTTP keyserver protocol", is normally spoken on a different port (11371/TCP) than regular HTTP. It could be that you're behind a firewall which blocks all but the most common ports.

Many keyservers *do* accept HKP on the regular HTTP port, and some of them also work with HKPS (which just shares the HTTPS port). Therefore try one of the following keyservers:

- `hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80`
- `hkps://pgp.mit.edu`
- `hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com`
- `hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80`
- <del>`hkps://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net`</del> ([dried up](https://sks-keyservers.net/status/))

Comment: Seems to be the case. Both `hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80` and `hkps://pgp.mit.edu` work.